# My landsknecht miss frequently, what affects accuracy?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-2

Sometimes, his attack misses. His miss is annoying, because he has the largest attack in my team. Why does he miss?  What affects missing an attack?  How can I increase his accuracy?

For comparison, here are the complete stats of my team (I have only 5 member in my guild):

```
Thomas (Landsknecht):
  LVL : 4
  HP  : 57
  TP  : 25
  STR : 15
  TEC : 6
  VIT : 8
  AGI : 7
  LUC : 6
  ATK : 36
  DEF : 23

Victor (Protector):
  LVL : 4
  HP  : 61
  TP  : 28
  STR : 7
  TEC : 7
  VIT : 11
  AGI : 5
  LUC : 7
  ATK : 27
  DEF : 28

Angeline (Medic):
  LVL : 4
  HP  : 43
  TP  : 49
  STR : 8
  TEC : 10
  VIT : 5
  AGI : 6
  LUC : 8
  ATK : 26
  DEF : 17

Marie (Troubador):
  LVL : 4
  HP  : 50
  TP  : 37
  STR : 5
  TEC : 9
  VIT : 5
  AGI : 8
  LUC : 9
  ATK : 25
  DEF : 15

Gerald (Gunner):
  LVL : 4
  HP  : 44
  TP  : 38
  STR : 9
  TEC : 8
  VIT : 6
  AGI : 5
  LUC : 9
  ATK : 30
  DEF : 16
```